# remembering button clicks from different screen

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

this is my first time trying to make an android app, or dealing with java, so please be patient with my questions :(

what i'm trying to do is to have screen-1 with a few buttons, when pressed, it will bring the user to screen-2 with another group of buttons. upon pressing a button in screen-2, the user will be brought to a new screen with some text based on which buttons he pressed, and in which order.

same goes with the other buttons in each screen.

what i already have is screen 1 full of buttons, and their ids. I'm not sure where to even begin for the next part. I can create an onClick activity for every button in screen-1, but how will screen-3 remember which buttons were pressed on screen-1 and screen-2?

activity_main.xml

```
<Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:onClick="button1OnClick"/>
                    <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button2"
                    android:onClick="button1OnClick2"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class Click extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open up screen 2? do i use intent??
        }
    });
}
```

}

activity_main2.xml

```
<Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:onClick="button1OnClick"/>
                    <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button2"
                    android:onClick="button1OnClick2"/>
```

MainActivity2.java

```
public class Click extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2.xml);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open up screen 3?  
        }
    });
}
```

}

screen-1 and screen-2 will share the same set of buttons. screen 3 will show which order, and which buttons were pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn how to pass data and parameters via **intents**.

Take a look at this:

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You pass that information along in the intent when you start the next activity.

eg in your `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` you'll do something like:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   // test for the arg you passed in and extract value eg
   String foostr = extras.getString(FOO_STRING);
   int fooint = extras.getInt(FOO_INT);
}
```

and in the caller that's starting the activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Screen-2.class);
intent.putExtra(FOO_INT,myInt);
intent.putExtra(FOO_STRING,myString);
startActivity(intent);
```